# How update field in index list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have "payment" field displayed as tag, boolean type in my database and if is it possible I'd like to add action on this field. In case when i click on this field i'd like change status from false to true, and reverse. And it all in index list.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Booking do

  permit_params :user_id, :race_id, :payment

  actions :all
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :race
    column :user
    column :payment
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

File routes.rb

```
 //config/routes.rb
  scope :admin do
    resources :bookings do
      member do
          get :payment
      end
    end
  end
```

My file booking.rb

```
//app/admin/booking.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Booking do

  permit_params :user_id, :race_id, :payment

  actions :all

  controller do
    def payment
        booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
        booking.payment = !booking.payment # toggle the status
        booking.save
        redirect_to booking_path(booking)
    end
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :race
    column :user
    column "Confirm" do |booking|
      link_to "Confirm", payment_booking_path(booking)
    end
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end

end
```

What is wrong with my code because i get "uninitialized constant BookingsController". My link: admin/bookings/16/payment

Answer (score 0):

In view

```
= link_to (@booking.payment ? true : false), payment_booking_path(@booking)
```

in controller

```
def payment
    booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    booking.payment = !booking.payment # toggle the status
    booking.save
    redirect_to booking_path(booking)
end
```

in routes

```
resources :bookings do
    member do
        get :payment
    end
end
```

Comment: which files and paths?